# HTML drop-down option box

Tags: html

I'm trying to make an option box, something where the user can select something from a dropdown box. Now the thing is I want the data that the user entered to then be displayed on the site. Also can this be done in HTML alone or will it need something else, if so please send links to video or code yourself.

Comment: <select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select> does what you describe..

Comment: Making your questions title constructive first would be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

let me see if I got you question right.
You want to create a select tag on your site, with some options in it, then when the user select the option he wants, that option goes to somewhere on the page. Is that it?

If it is, you will need a JavaScript library called jQuery, that allows you to change the HTML elements by the browser side, without needing to refresh the page.

Example

HTML File:

```
<select id="select_option">
  <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Value 3</option>
  <option value='4'>Value 4</option>
</select>
<div id="option_selected"></div>
```

Script file:

```
$( "#select_option" ).change(function() {
    $( "#option_selected" ).html($( this ).val());
});
```

What this code will do is, when the object with the id 'select_option' get changed, it will call the function 'change', there the content of the object with the id 'option_selected' will be overwritten ".html()" by the value of the select tag "$( this ).val()".

Links

jQuery: http://jquery.com/